# Can a client socket and a server socket have same ip and port on same machine?

Tags: sockets, server, client

Suppose you have a server socket that is bound to (ip1,port1). Can you have a client which is bound to (localport1, localip1)=(ip1,port1) i.e. to force the client to take a local port same as the server port and on same address?

In case yes or no, please explain the reason?

Comment: *By default*, no, a client will not be able to `bind()` its *local* endpoint to the same IP/Port that a local server is already bound to, unless it makes use of `SO_REUSEADDR`/`SO_REUSEPORT` (but if the server is coded properly, it should be preventing that, such as by using [`SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/so-exclusiveaddruse) on Windows). However,  the client can certainly `connect()` its *remote* endpoint to a server on the same machine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can we say that by default we can bind to same address and port but only when we use SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE  we cannot?

Comment: No, that is not true. In fact, many server apps don't use `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` like they should. And yet, the OS will still prevent the binding of a client socket to the same IP/Port as a server socket *by default*. There really is no good reason to ever `bind()` a client socket and a server socket to the same *local* IP/Port

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that there is "no good reason to ever bind() a client socket and a server socket to the same local IP/Port" as you mentioned but I am asking because may be the user uses a specific local port in his code, for some reason, and it happened that this port is used by a server. So what will happen then?

Comment: "*So what will happen then?*" - the `bind()` will fail with a `(WSA)EADDRINUSE` error, unless the client code explicitly enables `SO_REUSEADDR`/`SO_REUSEPORT` before calling `bind()` (most client apps don't do that, at least for TCP), and the server is not using `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`.  I suggest you do some research on what these socket options are and how they work, before you ask anymore questions on this topic.